# How can I customize different line colors and different font colors in the same StringGrid?

Tags: delphi

My goal is to customize a StringGrid with lines in alternating colors; customize the row and column titles with letters of one color and the other cells with letters of another color and; paint some cells with a certain color due to their content, keeping their content unchanged.

I already have tried to change the following properties settings:

TStringGrid.DefaultDrawing, TStringGrid.DrawingStyle, TStringGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color, TStrinGrid.Color, TSringGrid.Font.Color, TStringGrid.FixedColor, TStringGrig.Cells [ACol, ARow], TStringGrid.Canvas.FillRect and events: TStringGrid.OnDrawCell & TForm.OnCreate. But none worked.

When I paint a line, they are all painted with the same color, when I include text in a cell, all the texts in the other cells are painted with the same color.

**What I am trying to do this**:

When Form1 is created, StringGrid must be designed with the following characteristics:

- ColCount:= 32;
- RowCount:= 13;
- FixedCols:= 1;
- FixedRows := 1;
- FixedColor := Dark Gray (Col = 0 & Row = 0);
- Fixed Col filled := Col(1) = “01”, Col(2) = “02”, Col(3) = “03”, ... Col (31) = “31”  // (Font color := clYellow);
- Fixed Row filled := Row(1) = “January”, Row(2) = “February”, Row(3) = “March”, ... Row(12) = “December”   //   (Font color := clGreen);
- Rows must filled in alternated colors := Odd & Even like: 1, 3, 5, ... Light Blue   //   and: 2, 4, 6, ... Light Gray;

There is an Edit component (Edit1) in the Form1 to enter a Year. When a year is typed, all Cells must be filled like bellow:

- For example: Year 2020:
- January = Cells[1, 1] := “Wed”, Cells[2,1] := “Thu”, Cells[3,1] := “Fri”... Cells[31, 1]:= “Fri”   //   (Font color := clWhite);
- February = Cells[1, 2] := “Sat”, Cells[2, 2] := “Sun”, Cells[3, 2] := “Mon”... Cells[29, 1] := “Sat”   //   (Font color := clWhite); Until December... (if change the year (Edit1), that also has to be changed).
- Font color for the Fixed Col & Fixed Row must keep in clYellow and clGreen;

There is another Edit component (Edit2) in the Form1 to enter a holiday date (for example: December, 25, 2020). So, that cell should change its color to clRed, keeping text Cell[25, 12] := “Fri”.

I will be very glad if somebody could help me with this problem. I have no code to show because I tried too many times and changing all the time my codes trying to find a way to do that.

Sorry, I could not printed any picture because it is my first publication in StackOverflow.

Comment: Have you looked at numerous examples of using `OnDrawCell` to provide different cell colors?

Comment: There are many examples of using OnDrawCell with a TStringGrid. Saying you've *tried many things* but not including a single one seems rather unbelievable. It's also unclear why you formatted your own words as a blockquote, which is used for quoting the words of other people. Can you [edit] your post to provide a sample of what you've tiried that didn't work?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change color of text in a TStringGrid cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808016/change-color-of-text-in-a-tstringgrid-cell)

Comment: I might be wrong and sorry if I am, but your post seems to be a homework assignment. Doing your homework for you will not benefit you at all. Also, there's no clear question, but I guess you are primarily asking for help with how to change the background and text color. That has been asked before, and I linked to one question that deals with both. For the other requirements, like how to determine weekday for the first day of a year / month / week and how to save and retrieve holiday dates, you are welcome to post specific questions as new posts.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't ask the question correctly. It's my first time at Stackoverflow and I'm still learning how things work here.

Answer (score 1):

Small example of using different colors in StringGrid cells. You can define colors with your own rules

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  cn: TCanvas;
begin
  cn := TStringGrid(Sender).Canvas;
  if gdFixed in State then
     cn.Brush.Color := clYellow
  else
     cn.Brush.Color := RGB(64 * ACol, 255 - 64 * ARow, Random(256));
  cn.FillRect(Rect);
  cn.TextOut(Rect.Left + 2, Rect.Top + 2, Format('%d %d', [ ACol, ARow]));
end;
```

Comment: This does not exactly answer my need, however, I will study your example and try to adapt it to what I need.
Thanks for the answer.